# SQL - Extract the CITY from the string

Tags: sql

I have a field which is a ticket journey which always doesn't start with the CITY code and it varies from ticket to ticket.
Good Example:

```
HAM EK X/DXB EK DUR M/IT EK X/DXB EK HAM M/IT
```

However, there are some cases where it starts with "I-" or dates like "18JAN" or "18JAN16" or "18JAN2016". Below few examples:

```
I- HAM EK X/DXB EK DUR M/IT EK X/DXB EK HAM M/IT
18JAN HAM EK X/DXB EK DUR M/IT EK X/DXB EK HAM M/IT
18JAN16 HAM EK X/DXB EK DUR M/IT EK X/DXB EK HAM M/IT
18JAN2016 HAM EK X/DXB EK DUR M/IT EK X/DXB EK HAM M/IT
```

Hence, I wanted to have some assistance to only retrieve the 1st CITY from the string which in the above cases is **"HAM"**

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: how do you know which of them are city codes? do you have a separate table which stores city codes?

Comment: So is the city code always the first string after the first space?

Comment: These are IATA station codes, right? They all have three letters, like HAM, LAX, ORD, BOS, YCC. An airport has to be pretty small to have any digits  in its code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Declare @tblTest AS Table
(
   Ticket VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES ('I- HAM EK X/DXB EK DUR M/IT EK X/DXB EK HAM M/IT')
INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES ('18JAN HAM EK X/DXB EK DUR M/IT EK X/DXB EK HAM M/IT')
INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES ('18JAN16 HAM EK X/DXB EK DUR M/IT EK X/DXB EK HAM M/IT')
INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES ('18JAN2016 HAM EK X/DXB EK DUR M/IT EK X/DXB EK HAM M/IT')

SELECT  
    SUBSTRING
    (
        REPLACE
        (
            Ticket,
            SUBSTRING(Ticket,1,CHARINDEX(' ',Ticket)),
            ''
        ),
        0,
        CHARINDEX
        (
            ' ',
            REPLACE
            (
                Ticket,
                SUBSTRING(Ticket,1,CHARINDEX(' ',Ticket)),
                ''
            )
        )
    )
FROM @tblTest
```

Comment: What about  the string starting with HAM.. ('HAM EK X/DXB EK DUR M/IT EK X/DXB EK HAM M/IT') ??

Comment: OP not mention that ticket start from city

Comment: it is mentioned.. Read the question carefully..

Comment: he worry about some cases, if he also wants with starting then no any solution possible because city can be anything, it can be "18JAN" also

Comment: that is right.. :) :P But he wants so.. In my query i just made a check whether the  first letter starting with a number or 'I_' , But it may fail if there a city starts with a number.. As you said.. :)

Answer (score 0):

For Sql Server, Use the below script.

```
DECLARE @data VARCHAR(150)='18JAN HAM EK X/DXB EK DUR M/IT EK X/DXB EK HAM M/IT'

SELECT CASE WHEN @data LIKE 'I_%' THEN SUBSTRING(@data,CHARINDEX(' ', @data),CHARINDEX(' ', @data,CHARINDEX(' ',@data) + 1) + 1-CHARINDEX(' ', @data)) 
            WHEN @data LIKE '[0-9]%' THEN SUBSTRING(@data,CHARINDEX(' ', @data),CHARINDEX(' ', @data,CHARINDEX(' ',@data) + 1) + 1-CHARINDEX(' ', @data))
            ELSE SUBSTRING(@data,1,CHARINDEX(' ', @data)) END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **SUBSTRING**, if you know where you are selecting from which would work if you always new the length of the prefix, however there is little point of this as if you are searching '**cities**' then you will be driving this from somewhere (either a cities table or hard codes values). SO I imagine you will search for something like

```
WHERE field = "%HAM%" or WHERE field IN ('list','of','cities')
```

and then use this to inform the query outputs.

My advice is, don't think about selecting from the string that you are searching from but instead use the inputs that searching with to inform the output. I hope this makes sense. If you have queries to look at I will try and make some suggestions.